# Demanding SASL authentication on port 25 rejects all of my incomming email

Tags: postfix, smtp, sasl

I am using this chunk of code inside `/etc/postfix/master.cf` to force people to securely *"subimt"* email through port `465` which uses protocol SMTPS. SMTPS supports mandatory TLS which I use to demand from clients to 1st *"encrypt"* connection using mandatory TLS and 2nd *"authenticate"* using SASL mechanism.

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#
  -o smtpd_use_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-rsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-rsa.key
  -o smtpd_tls_eccert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-ecdsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_eckey_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-ecdsa.key
#
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#
```

This works as expected. It actualy works great!

---

I wanted to secure the port `25` in the same way but it looks like it is imposible as this port has two **inbound** functionalities i.e. *"submission"* and *"relay recieving"* *(it is stupid to prolong the life of this port that we should get rid of ASAP)*.

On port `25` there is only protocol SMTP which does not support mandatory TLS! So for **inbound** email i.e. "submission" and "relay receiving" all that can be enabled is oportunistic TLS *(can be hacked)*. So all I can enable is a bad *"encryption"* which can later be enhanced using DANE *(can't be hacked easily)*.

So for port `25` I have hopes for my *"encryption"* to be sufficient at some point while I don't understand how to set up SASL *"authentication"*!

I tried using this chunk of code in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` where 1st part of the code sets up oportunistic TLS the second part of code should set up SASL *"authentication"*.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtp
#
  -o smtpd_use_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-rsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-rsa.key
  -o smtpd_tls_eccert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-ecdsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_eckey_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-ecdsa.key
#
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination
#
```

Unfortunately, I discovered that line:

```
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

**on one hand** forces clients, who want to *"submit"* email through port `25`,  to *`"authenticate"`* and **on the other hand** rejects all the "relay received" email arriving from other MTA!

So how can I achieve both:

- preventing anyone from the internet to *"submit"* email using port `25` on my server.
- *"relay receive"* all the email comming from other MTA to my port `25`.

Comment: If you want incoming emails (relaying) on 25 port you can't combine it with strict SASL otherwise external mail servers won't be able to submit anything.

Comment: @Hardoman I already understand this, but what is the solution?

Comment: Do not require SASL authentication on port 25 if you want incoming mail to work.  There is no other solution.

Comment: Your request is contrary to the design of the whole SMTP auth approach, so there is no solution.

Comment: @tater So what you are saying is to let anyone send email using our server? Because no SASL means exactly this.

Comment: Of course I am not saying that. The only mail accepted on port 25 should be that for a local/internal address.  Mail to be relayed externally should be submitted by clients on an authenticated port such as 465/587.

Comment: @tater But if I accept only email *"submission"* from local addresses, wouldn't that block all *"relay recieved"* emails as well? Are there separate Postfix configuration parameters for *"submission"* and *"relay recieving"*??? If there are I am very interested. (According to [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-2.3.2) *"relay sender"* and *"relay receiver"* are correct terms therefore also *"relay send"* and *"relay receive"*)?

Comment: The default Postfix configuration was already secured. There was no need or reason to undo it or to add unnecessary stuff. Go back to it.

Comment: I don't just trust default configuration. I want it explicitly configured if anyone knows how to do that.